# How to remove an "Alias" in cmDer?

Tags: cmder

I created a test "alias" in cmDer

```
alias testalias = "dir * a ".
```

How to remove the alias I created?

Comment: Did you create the alias for the current running session or a permanent one? For what I can see, it is just an alias for the current session, So if you restart the cmDer, it should be gone

Comment: I restarted but the "alias" not be gone.

Comment: Hey @EversonRafael if that is the case, please see my answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the alias isn't gone after restarting your console, it means that it got created permanent.

Removing a created alias is pretty simple, you just need to execute the following command:

```
alias /d [alias name]
```

In your case will be something like:

```
alias /d testalias
```

Also, if you didn't change the default alias that are created when you unzip the app, you can simple rely on another alias which is:

```
unalias [alias name]
```

Hope this helps

PS: if you want to see which are your available aliases, just execute `alias` and you will get them

Comment: I am using cmder for Windows 7 and `alias /d testalias` works fine for me. Rest are deprecated.